# npm doesn't work in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, node.js

I have XCode and NodeJS installed but can't use npm.
Here is how I installed npm:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

but when I try to install a package like express it doesn't response and my command line goes to "just type" mode that I just can type characters including enter.
I'm trying to install express with this command:

```
npm install express
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing. I am on Ubuntu 11.04 .

Comment: npm just takes a *really* long time to return it's results for me. Try an `npm search` and see if it comes back with a result: `npm search express`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in node, not npms fault. Try this:

```
npm install express --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Basically, https is partially broken in the newest versions of node.

Edit: Github Issue here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1531

Comment: I'll accept your answer after I try it on my Mac, I'm on PC now. Thanks

Comment: I need a guide for installing packages without package manager, does somebody have a link?